# elimination of distortion of the viewing angle

Tags: opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

- What I have?

> Photo taken exactly in the center of the object.

- What do I need?

> Remove the distortion that occurs due to the natural viewing angle. I
> need the image to be "flat" and "look" at me from any point of the
> image. So, for example, in this example, after this processing, all
> fasteners on which the wires are hanging should disappear.

How should I do it?

[image: Photo]

Comment: this isn't possible with a 2D camera, unless the object you are interesting is completely planar (or at least nearly planar).

Comment: You are lucky: this is impossible. Done.

Comment: Bad news: if you really want to do that, unless you have strong a priori information about the geometry of the scene, you will need a 3D camera/camera pair, complicated processing and accept imperfect results.

Comment: Other options: look from a very long distance, with suitable magnification, or use a telecentric lens (will cost you an arm for a large diameter).

Comment: Final option: use a strong collimated light source to obtain hard shadows and no penumbra. Then by a tricky matching and reconstruction process, you can partially estimate the height of the features and erase what you want by inpainting. Needless to say, difficult and poor results.

Comment: @YvesDaoust 
> if you really want to do that, unless you have strong a priori information about the geometry of the scene
//
I have some information. All objects are photographed in the center at right angles to the plane. Is it possible to use some kind of algorithm or come up with something based on this information?

Comment: This is not "a priori information on the scene".

Comment: That looks like a board for making wireing harnesses. I would draw it out graphically and you can then include the wire colours and sizes as well as the connector details